# Spring WS and PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I have two endpoints using annotations. I want to apply different interceptors to each of them. (one being a secure interceptor and the other not being secure) Is there a way to do this using `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`? Anyone have an idea?

According to the applicationContext-ws.xml of the airline example that comes with Spring:

> The endpoint mappings map from a
>   request to an endpoint. Because we
>   only want the security interception to
>   occur for the
>   `GetFrequentFlyerMileageEndpoint`, we
>   define two mappings: one with the
>   securityInterceptor, and a general one
>   without it.

So is the only way to do this is to have two different mappings: `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` and `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping` for the secure ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give an interceptor set to an `EndpointMapping`, then those interceptors will apply to all Endpoints mapped by that `EndpointMapping`. So if you want some Endpoints to get a different set of interceptors to other Endpoints, then yes, you need two different `EndpointMapping` beans, one with the secure interceptor and mapping to the secure endpoints, and another with no interceptors and mapping to the unsecured endpoints.

Which `EndpointMapping` implementations you use is dependent on the application and which kinds of Endpoints it uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the sws:interceptors element in your application context to specify particular interceptors with particular endpoints, filtered by their soapAction or payloadRoot attributes.

From:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor

```
<sws:interceptors>
  <bean class="samples.MyGlobalInterceptor"/>
  <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.example.com">
    <bean class="samples.MyPayloadRootInterceptor"/>
  </sws:payloadRoot>
  <sws:soapAction value="http://www.example.com/SoapAction">
    <bean class="samples.MySoapActionInterceptor1"/>
    <ref bean="mySoapActionInterceptor2"/>
  </sws:soapAction>
</sws:interceptors>

<bean id="mySoapActionInterceptor2" class="samples.MySoapActionInterceptor2"/>
```